# Awk: remove first few fields from CSV

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I'm using this command to get my output in csv.

```
awk 'ORS="," {print $2}'
```

I get the output in the following format:

```
a,b,c,name,col1,col2,col3,
```

Here I would like to delete 'name' and everything before 'name' and get only the column names. Note that column names can have the work 'name' too, which I donot want to delete. So I am okay with only deleting the first occurrence of name. Can this be done with awk?

I have tried:

```
awk 'NR >4 {print $2}' | awk '{ORS=","}'
```

and various combinations, none of which worked.

Comment: you can do with sed  sed -i 's/.*name,//' /path/youfile

Comment: That sed command removed all occurrences of column names with 'name' in their name.

Comment: just as asked  all before name & name itself :)    'Here I would like to delete 'name' and everything before 'name' ' it is a logical and :)

Comment: @francoisP, the greedy `.*` eats everything up to the _last_ occurrence of `name`, so if the input is `blah,name,othername,bleh`,  `othername` is gone too, and only `bleh` is left.

Comment: ah ok I think it was the first ... my fault :)

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: please edit your question and add a small representative sample of the input as well as the expected output. Remember to anonymise your sample data if it contains any personal or sensitive information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a,b,c,name,col1,col2,col3,` are the second fields of each line in the original, then you could do the test against `name` at the same time you pick out these (this still leaves the annoying final comma):

```
$ awk -vORS=, 'p {print $2}; $2 == "name" {p=1} ' input; echo
col1,col2,col3,
```

So, starting with what you had (`awk 'ORS="," {print $2}'`), we add a test variable `p` that tells if `name` has already been seen. We print the second field only if `p` has been set to a true value earlier, and set it to true if the second field happens to be `name`. With the tests in this order, the `name` column itself is not printed. We could also ignore empty lines in input by changing `p {print $2}` to `$0 && p {print $2}`, that is, make a truthy (nonempty) input line a condition for the print, along with `p`.

I assumed here that the original input looks like this:

```
x a
x b
x c
x name
x col1
x col2
x col3
```

Alternatively, starting from the comma-separated list `a,b,c,name,somename,othername,col3,`:

```
$ echo 'a,b,c,name,somename,othername,col3,' | 
    sed -e 's/.*,name,//' -e s'/,$//'
somename,othername,col3
```

Note the commas on both sides of `,name,` in the pattern, they keep the greedy `.*` from catching the later names that end in `...name`.

Comment: This almost worked. I now get ",col1,col2,col3,". I need to remove the first comma after the name

Comment: I think the extra comma at the beginning might be due to leading whitespaces/new lines?

Comment: @user2441441, mhmh, well, I can't see the original data you used to produce the comma-separated list, so it's hard to say. Empty lines would cause that, though.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to remove the extra comma?

Comment: Can you please explain how the command works awk -vORS=, 'p {print $2}; $2 == "name" {p=1} '?

Comment: @user2441441, change the test `p` to `$0 && p` to ignore empty lines. (an empty string is false so the test fails on empty lines). I added some notes about the logic.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming file contents as below:

```
$ cat myfile
a,b,c,name,col1,col2,col3,forename,surname,name5,foo,name,name6
$
```

`awk` solution

```
$ awk -F',name,' '{print substr($0,index($0,$2))}' myfile
col1,col2,col3,forename,surname,name5,foo,name,name6
$
```

`perl` solution.

```
$ perl -pe 's/^.*?name,//' myfile
col1,col2,col3,forename,surname,name5,foo,name,name6
$
```